# Comunicación entre websocket y mi controller symfony

Tags: php, symfony, websocket

Utilizando este websocket, que esta funcionando actualmente:

```
class WebsocketServerCommand extends Command
{
    protected static $defaultName = "run:websocket-server";

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $messageHandler = new MessageHandler();
        $port = 3001;
        $output->writeln("Starting server on port " . $port);
        $server = IoServer::factory(
            new HttpServer(
                new WsServer(
                    $messageHandler
                )
            ),
            $port
        );
        $server->run();
        return 0;
    }

    public static function getMessageHandler() {
        return $messageHandler;
    }
}
```

Consigo que los dispositivos se conecten y se comuniquen entre ellos, pero quiero que desde un controller pueda enviar mensajes a los dispositivos.
No se como instanciar todo esto para poder hacer por ejemplo un:

`WebsocketServerCommand::getMessageHandler()->send("Hola")`

gracias